# OpenGL version issue with Panda3d

Tags: python, windows, opengl, nvidia, panda3d

I am trying to get Panda3d set up and running correctly. I keep getting this error when I try to render a model with the 'pview' method,

```
:display:gsg:glgsg(warning): Driver possibly misreported GL_VERSION!  
Unable to detect correct OpenGL version.
```

I'm using windows 10 OS, OpenGL 4.5, NIVIDIA Quadro P3200 and Intel graphics card. I've already changed the global settings in the NIVIDIA control panel to use the NIVIDIA GPU by default. Any ideas on how to fix this error and start redering 3d models with panda3d?

Comment: How did you install Panda3D?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez I used pip